# SQL Query Minimizer : CREATE + ALTER => CREATE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Are there any tools available which can give me 
**a single CREATE query** 
when I give a 
**CREATE & number of ALTER queries as input**

For Example,
INPUT:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    student_id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    age INT);

ALTER TABLE student ADD(
    address VARCHAR(200)
);
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    student_id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    age INT,
    address VARCHAR(200));
```

This is just a simple example, I need a tool which can work for more complex queries as well.

---

Real Problem:

I have set of files having multiple SQL queries.
Therefore, I need this task to be done in bulk.

**Example**

Input File:

```
CREATE query (table 1)
CREATE query (table 2)
CREATE query (table 3)
ALTER  query (table 1)
ALTER  query (table 3)
ALTER  query (table 2)
ALTER  query (table 2)
ALTER  query (table 1)
......
```

Expected Output File:

```
CREATE query (table 1)
CREATE query (table 2)
CREATE query (table 3)
......
```

There are a lot of tables in a file, may be around 30.

Comment: No problems. Execute all statements (on temporarily created database, for example), then get `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with full code which takes all statements into account.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dec4ba3c558ea8eacfbd4389a64c05a1

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE is really helpful, but now I have a set of files with a large bunch of queries. Finding queries belonging to a particular table and creating temporary tables may not be helpful in that case.

Comment: So, is there any facility to do this in bulk ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use XAMPP server to do it.....
It has basic GUI window in which you could just click and get your query, without actually typing it...
It can save time

REGARD